# Возникло затруднение с синтаксическим разбором

Tags: синтаксис

Является ли предложение "прибыл тридцать один делегат" полным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это полное предложение. В нем есть все члены, необходимые для понимания смысла этого предложения.

**Ср.: Сегодня я иду в кино. Завтра - в театр.** Первое предложение полное. Второе - неполное. В нем отсутствуют главные члены предложения: подлежащее и сказуемое (Завтра **я иду** в театр). Но их можно восстановить из предыдущего контекста.

Comment: Я бы дополнил ответ указанием на подлежащее и сказуемое в рассматриваемом примере.